# How can I set two select menu's in jquery mobile side by side and fill the width of the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two select buttons and I'm trying to put them side by side and take up the width of the screen. I've gotten sorta close either using a grid, or putting them in a control group. With the grid the buttons each take up 50% of the screen but they do not touch. In the control group the select buttons touch but I can't get it to fit the screen. Here are the two implementations. [Here is the js fiddle to show what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/aFGxy/4/)

```
 <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
        <select name="select_networks" id="select_networks">
            <option value="1/1">Everyone</option>
            <option value="2/1">Friends</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select_sort" id="select_sort">
            <option value="1">Points</option>
            <option value="2">New</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"> <select name="select_networks" id="select_networks">
                <option value="1/1">Everyone</option>
                <option value="2/1">Friends</option>
            </select></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <select name="select_sort" id="select_sort">
                <option value="1">Points</option>
                <option value="2">New</option>
            </select></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try adding this css

    .ui-select div  {
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    margin-left:8px;
    }

even though I ma not sure about the jqyer mobile css framework the above should work​

Answer (score 2):

Using the navbar you can do this, just make sure it's not wrapped in the content div

- http://jsfiddle.net/aFGxy/9/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="contest" data-theme="a">

   <div data-role="content">



    </div>

    <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                     <select name="select_networks" id="select_networks" data-corners="false">
                        <option value="1/1">Everyone</option>
                        <option value="2/1">Friends</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <select name="select_sort" id="select_sort" data-corners="false">
                        <option value="1">Points</option>
                        <option value="2">New</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</div>
```

​